# GraphQL Query resolvers as separate Web transactions

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, newrelic, apm

I have a Java Spring Boot service exposing GraphQL API. NewRelic identify all the queries as `configuredGraphQLHttpServlet` Web transaction as all of them are exposed via a single /graphql API . How can we track each GraphQL query resolver as different web transactions?

Comment: @Micheal Have you got this answer? actually I have same question didn't get any solution also for the Node application with graphQL

Comment: Node is a little different.  I'll see if I can find documentation but I think André is going to post a link to some hopefully helpful documentation for the Java version soon.

Comment: @RahulSaini perhaps it might make sense to ask a similar question with Node tags etc. if possible so its easier to find.

Comment: Tag me or whatever on the Node question and I'll get someone from the Node team to answer or I'll find the information and and answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

The New Relic Java agent starting with version 7.4.0 (Oct 2021) has auto-instrumentation for GraphQL. Use 7.4.3 or higher though.

With it the transactions are going to be named based on the query.

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/tree/main/instrumentation/graphql-java-16.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AOP to set transaction name base on graphql method. It will look like below.

[image]

Comment: How would that be, can you show a code example. Are these not different http endpoints.

Comment: You can try like this. Hope it might help :)
`
@Aspect
@Component
public class NewRelicGraphQLAspect {

    @After("isGraphQLRequest()")
    public void doSecurityCheck(JoinPoint point) {
        String methodName = point.getSignature().getName();
        NewRelic.setTransactionName("GraphQL", methodName);
    }

    @Pointcut("within(com.example.server.graphql.resolver..*)")
    private void isGraphQLRequest() {
    }
}
`